# Series to Sum Equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, summation, arithmetic

I have this series and I want to convert it to the Summation form.

$1+(1+\alpha _{1})+(1+\alpha _{1})(1+\alpha _{2})+(1+\alpha _{1})(1+\alpha _{2})(1+\alpha _{3})+...$

I know that the next series is the result of multiplying by the previous series.

Let the $a _{1} = 1$, and $a _{2} = a _{1}(1+\alpha _{1})$. This is what I mean. But, then how to change all of those series to the Summation form?

Comment: This is a sum of products. If you expand the products, you will get a nasty result.

Comment: @nickchalkida Please suggest in comments what you think might improve the question; and confirm with the OP whether you have read their mind, before editing.   Use comments to help the OP improve the question.   But don't assume you are helping when you transform a question into something it never was.

Comment: Thanks all! My question is just as is. it has been answered. sorry if I wrote in bad structure as I am new in here. I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write finite products using the product symbol $\prod$ as
\begin{align*}
\left(1+\alpha_1\right)\left(1+\alpha_2\right)\cdots \left(1+\alpha_n\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\alpha_k\right)
\end{align*}
With this notation we can write the series as
\begin{align*}
&1+\left(1+\alpha_1\right)+\left(1+\alpha_1\right)\left(1+\alpha_2\right)+\cdots\\
&\qquad=1+\prod_{k=1}^1\left(1+\alpha_k\right)+\prod_{k=1}^2\left(1+\alpha_k\right)+\cdots\\
&\qquad=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\alpha_k\right)\\
&\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\alpha_k\right)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
In the last line we note the empty product $\prod_{k=1}^0\left(1+\alpha_k\right)$ with upper bound less than lower bound is by definition $1$.

If we like we can also expand the products. Let $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ denote the $n$ element set of natural numbers $1$ to $n$. We can write
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\alpha_k\right)=\sum_{S\subset[n]}\prod_{j\in S}\alpha_j\tag{2}
\end{align*}
An example of (2) with small $n=2$: We obtain
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^2\left(1+\alpha_k\right)&=\left(1+\alpha_1\right)\left(1+\alpha_2\right)\\
&=1+\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_2\tag{3}
\end{align*}
and the four terms in (3) correspond to the subsets $\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}=[2]$ as stated for general $[n]$ in the sum of (2).

> Combining (1) and (2) we can write
> \begin{align*}
> &1+\left(1+\alpha_1\right)+\left(1+\alpha_1\right)\left(1+\alpha_2\right)+\cdots\\
> &\qquad=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\alpha_k\right)\\
> &\qquad \color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{S\subset[n]}\prod_{j\in S}\alpha_j}
> \end{align*}

Comment: I think this is helpful. Your explanation is clear enough for me. Many thanks!

Comment: @xevender: You're welcome!